# Where to put static fields used in builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Using a builder pattern I want to have static fields used in all instances. Do I put them in the Url class or in the UrlBuilder class as static fields or do I extract them into a new class to only hold the static fields?

The expected result is the ability to create a Url instance by using the Builder class and a switch case logic in the UrlBuilder constructor.

Here is a code example:

```
public class Url {

  //required parameters
  private String homePage;
  private String boardSuffix;

  public String getHomePage() {
    return homePage;
  }

  public String getBoardSuffix() {
    return boardSuffix;
  }

  private Url(UrlBuilder builder) {
    this.homePage = builder.homePage;
    this.boardSuffix = builder.boardSuffix;
  }

  //Builder class
  public static class UrlBuilder {

    //required parameters
    private String homePage;
    private String boardSuffix;

    public UrlBuilder(String homePage, String boardSuffix) {
      this.homePage = homePage;
      this.boardSuffix = boardSuffix;
    }

    public Url build() {
      return new Url(this);
    }

  }

}
```

I've tried placing the static fields in a "Constants" enum, but got lost in the reflection of enums, while trying to prepare tests.

Comment: *"I want to have static fields used in all instances"* - `static` fields **belong to the class**, i.e. they shared among all the instances (as opposed to instance fields). Therefore, the presented problem makes no sense. For the purpose of modifying static fields, you can expose static methods in your class.

Comment: Hey Alexander! Thanks for the reply.

Do I put the static fields in the Url class or in a different class and then modify them with a method in the Url class? Or do I put the methods in the other class, where the static fields are?

Comment: *"Do I put the static fields in the Url class or in a different class"* - you need to declare both static fields and methods for modifying them in the **same class**. To determine to which class exactly it should be, think to about the role of these fields and place them where they fit best. As an analogy, in the real life you would want the fridge located in the kitchen and bathtub in the bathroom, because that's where they are most suitable.